# How do I remove duplicate content within a sigle excel cell

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have individual cells in excel with the following content in each of them

```
http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/m1423.jpg|http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/m1423.jpg

http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/rt2899.jpg|http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/rt2899.jpg
```

This is one cell in a long row for a dump of data for products within an ecommerce site. A data migration has somehow added the same image more than once to the same product. Each separate image image is separated by the Pipe "|" symbol.

I want to search each cell in this column of the sheet and remove the duplicated image reference and the Pipe symbol.

So the examples above become

```
http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/m1423.jpg
```

and

```
http://www.teng.mossdemo.com.au/wp-content/uploads/images/products/rt2899.jpg
```

Comment: do a formula for each cell; search for pipe symbol; use left function to extract text up to pipe; convert formula to value with copy/paste special. `=LEFT(<cell address>,SEARCH("|",<cell address>)-1)` or something pretty close to that!

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answer of finding the pipe with SEARCH is a good general answer, however in this instance as the source string is always twice the length of the desired we can just chop it in half with the formula below and drag it down.

=LEFT(A1,(LEN(A1)-1)/2)

Comment: Good ppint, but  since the length will always be odd, it should be LEN(A1)-1.

Comment: I've amended it to include -1 . Excel 2007 (at least) will implicitly floor decimals in the LEN function so the prior function does work, but probably best not to rely the type conversion

Comment: You're right. And in fact something like `=LEFT("cat",1.5)` returns "c", which I hadn't realized. Anyways +1, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a formula, you can use Data>Text to Columns, which is a good thing to know about. Select the entire column and then you up the dialog. In step one choose "Delimited" and in step two choose the pipe symbol:

[image]

When you're finished, delete the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this works for some more complex scenarios. I think it should work for this one as well.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(C2,(FIND(LEFT(C2,20),C2,2)-2)),C2)
```

I entered this into D2 and copied it all the way down the column. I then copied and pasted the values back into Column C.

The problem I had was that not all of the cells in my column had duplicate text. Of those that did, the duplications were not delineated by any unique character (There was a single space in front of each duplication.), and the duplicated text was often an incomplete duplication so the length was not consistently symmetrical.

The "20" is an arbitrary number of characters I picked for excel to use from the front of the text to identify where the text started to repeat. There are enough people here who know excel better than I who can explain what the rest of the formula does. I figured it out by poking around.